# Enable horizntal scroll for mobile site

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I want to enable horizontal scroll for my asp mvc **mobile** website.
How can i do that for my table?
It has to be done in css file or in cshtml? Thanks in advance for any help.
Because now it looks like this:

[screen here](http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/8dce9077.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the table in a scrollable `div`

```
<div style="max-width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll">
  <table>
  ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I tried this earlier. [HERE](http://www.fotoszok.pl/upload/0ee1b55f.png) is the result and i couldn't scroll it on mobile site as you can see.